# minted complilation problem when changing machine

Tags: texmaker, windows, minted, shell-escape

I'm writing a document science 7 months in my office desktop and every things worked well, but when I take all files to compile in my home computer, I got this error compilation with the minted package ... I don't know if it is specific to minted (as I see in the net) :

```
! Package minted Error: You must invoke LaTeX with the -shell-escape flag.See the minted package documentation for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... \usepackage
```

I'm working on a windows 7 machine with texmaker, 
I use the same version in the two machines ... I recently synchronize the MikTek packages in the two also, but it works well in my office computer. 
Thank you !

Comment: exactly as the error says. you must use `pdflatex --shell-escape`  not `pdflatex` with minted (so that it is allowed to run a python program to do the syntax highlighting) Presumably you have customised one of your editors to do that but not the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, you're right @David Carlistle, but There are some things to do before the minted package works : so to INSTALL MINTED PACKAGE AND USE IT IN TEXMAKER, you should follow these steps :

1 - Install python 2.7

2 - Install distribute-0.6.49.zip (md5) and extract files where ever you want but keep the path in mind.

3 - add "C:\Python27" in windows path variables ("My Computer" > "Properties" > "Advanced" > "Environment Variables" > "Path").

4 - Go to the distribute path in the command prompt and lunch `easy_install Pygments`, you should have this result :

[image: Pygmentize Installation]

5 - Now, go on TexMaker : Options/Configure TexMaker/Commands and add in the PdfLatex field (`--shell-escape`), you should have this result :

[image: PdfLatexField]

Now you can compile with no errors, for example, this simple code :

```
    \begin{minted}[mathescape,
                   linenos=false,
                   numbersep=5pt,
                   gobble=2,
                   %showspaces,
                   frame=lines,
                   framesep=2mm,
                   %fontfamily=
                   %fontsize=\tiny{matlab}
                   ]{Matlab} 
     for i=1:10 
       i=i+1;
     end
     \end{minted}
```

That's it ! 
Enjoy ...